# recognize `0` as a true in PHP if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a function in Wordpress ([has_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_filter)) that returns `false` or `integer`.

I want to recognize `0` as a true in if statement, so I'm writing like this.

```
if(!(false === has_filter( $tag, $function_to_check )))
{ 
    echo "true!"; 
}
```

But I think this code is a little complicated. Is there better way to write in situation like this?

I'm asking this question not in wordpress.stackexange.com because it is about php itself.

Comment: Does that code work? If it does is that bad? It may seem complicated to you but if it works it looks good to me.

Comment: Code is code. Sometimes it looks bad, even if it’s the best way to accomplish something.

Comment: you can change `if (!(... === ...))` into `if (... !== ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
if(is_int(has_filter( $tag, $function_to_check ))){ echo "true!"; }
```

https://www.php.net/is_int

Answer (score 0):

You could write the following instead, not much different, but a little bit shorter:

```
if ( has_filter( $tag, $function_to_check ) !== false) { 
    echo "true!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip one level of parens and write it like this:

```
if( false !== has_filter( $tag, $function_to_check ) )
{ 
    echo "true!"; 
}
```

Because doing `if (!(... === ...))` is the same as doing `if (... !== ...)`